# Decidability of the theory $(\mathbb{R},+,*,\max,\leq)$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, reference-request

I know that the theory $(\mathbb{R},+,*,\leq)$ is decidable (Tarski 51) and I was wondering wether the decidability status is known when extending this theory with the $\max$ operator.

Do you have any references/intuitions/proofs on this question?

Thank you.

Comment: How does $\max$ work in first order logic? I can't see a way to do if that's not a trivial application of $\leq$

Comment: If $\max$ is a binary operator defined as usual (return the larger of the two numbers), then it is a conservative extension of the usual $(\Bbb R,+,\cdot,\leq)$ and therefore decidable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't see how. I'm sorry can you elaborate?

Comment: $$\max(x,y)=z\iff (z=x\land y\leq x) \lor (z=y\land x\leq y) $$

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry I must be really tired .... My excuses ...